# What does it mean to "replace all variables with the residuals after projections on any additional exogenous regressors"

Tags: applied-econometrics, stata, instrumental-variable

I am conducting IV Regression and to make sure that my instrument is not weak, I want to use Montiel Olea & Pflueger (2013) robustness test. (see: [Paper by Montiel Olea & Plueger (2013)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00401706.2013.806694) ).
To do so, you need their stata ado "weakivtest", which is an post-regression command. However, in their paper they specify 4 steps how to conduct this test (without stata ado). The first steps says the following: *If there are additional exogenous regressors, replace all variables by their projection residuals onto those exogenous regressors. Normalize instruments to be orthonormal.* (see Montiel Olea & Pflueger, 2013: p.360).

How do I do that? Do I have to run a regression and simply use the residuals? Which regression to run: first stage or second stage or...? Or don't I need to do any of this because the stata ado takes care about it? (note that normalizing my instrument is not a problem).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1$ be the $(n \times k_1)$ matrix for the endogenous variables and $X_2$ the exogenous $(n \times k_2)$ matrix for the additional exogenous variables.

Then the residuals from regressing $X_1$ on $X_2$ is given by:
$$
M_{X_2} X_1,
$$
where
$$
M_{X_2} = (I - X_2(X_2'X_2)^{-1}X_2'))
$$
Where $I$ is the identity matrix.

So you replace $X_1$ by $M_{X_2}X_1$ in the regression.

Alternatively, you can regress every variable in $X_1$ on all the variables in $X_2$ (i.e. running $k_1$ regressions). Then take the residuals of these regressions in the second stage.